# How to find which process removing a directory in linux?

Tags: linux

Please let me know the commmand or the way to find which process is removing the a directory in linux. I have checked with inotify it is telling whether the directory is deleted or not. But I want to know which process is deleting the directory in linux.

Comment: what do you mean which process? Do you mean PID? if yes - the PID is kind of random number that you can not find after the process is finished. If some process is deleting some directory after finishing I think you can not identify the PID.  Please be more clearly.

Comment: You get these infos in environment variables of the incron script, see my answer on bottom.

Comment: It seems to be possible with SystemTap: `Monitor the files are deleted using systemtap` http://www.itsprite.com/monitor-the-files-are-deleted-using-systemtap. Could you give it a try?

Comment: Perhaps set the permissions on the directory so that it can't be removed, and then watch for what whines?

Comment: If you want to know which user deleted some files or folder you need to learn how to make accounting on your linux machine.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: `auditd` helped me. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/50016/988855).

Answer (score 4):

There is no command or way to know which process removed a directory in linux.

To make an analogy, it's like asking for the name, id and picture of the guy who painted this:

[image: rock art]

He has died long ago and today there's nothing you can do to know those informations.

The same thing applies to your directory and the process who's responsible for that. It has been removed, and except if the process doing it explicitly tells you it did it (like writing it in a log, or spying on it using `strace`), you can't know it did it.

Comment: Funny, but the situation is not so bad.

Answer (score 1):

There is a functionality in linux named *inotify*. This can watch for file or directory changes. For every.

```
man inotify
```

There is a daemon named `incron`, which will be able to call any of your script, giving him the parameters of process doing the action you are watching.

In your case, you need to create a watch for directory removal operations in the parent directory of your directory disappearing. At first time it will be not really trivial (its configuration is a little bit harder as the cron's), but finally you get what you wanted.

*Incron can give its called script in environment variables the data what you need!* The only thing what you need to do is to dump the whole environment variable list into a temporary file.

Comment: This is only partially useful. As far as I understand, `inotify`/`incrond` can show when a file was removed, but not by which user and process.

Comment: @tolache I am not so sure - as I can remember, you get a lot of metadata in various environment variables, very likely also this is among them.